# Why is this error in my Scheme Cube-Root program showing up?

Tags: function, math, error-handling, functional-programming, scheme

So I'm working my way through [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-10.html), and one of the problems (1.8) is to implement a cube-root procedure analogous to the square-root procedure using the [Newton-Raphson method](https://socratic.org/questions/how-do-you-use-newton-s-method-to-approximate-the-value-of-cube-root).  I wrote the program and tried executing it, but got this error: `*: number required, but got #<Closure> [cubert, cubeiter, cubeiter, good-enough, cube, sq, *]`

This is my code:

```
(define (sq x)
  (* x x))
(define (cube x)
  (*(sq x) x))
(define (abs x) 
  (if (< x 0) 
    (-x) 
    x))
(define (good-enough guess x)
  (< (abs (- x (cube guess)) )0.0001))
(define (improve guess x)
  (- guess (/ (- (cube guess) 3) (* 3 (sq x)))))
(define (cubeiter guess x)
  (if (good-enough guess x)
       guess
       (cubeiter improve x)))
(define (cubert x) (cubeiter 1.0 x))

(cubert 27)
```

Could anyone possible explain what this error means and how I can fix it?  what is `#<Closure>`?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#<Closure>` is the implementations method of representing a procedure object. If `x` evaluates to that then `(x ...)` calls that procedure. Eg. `(+ 2 3) ; ==> 5`, but `+ ; ==> #<Closure>`. (`+` is a primitive so it might display differently, but it really doesn't matter. You are not supposed to print it :) )

I see you call `(cubeiter improve x)`, but it doesn't seem correct that `guess` is supposed to be a procedure since the initial call passes `1.0` which is a number. Clearly one of them are wrong. Perhaps you was supposed to call `improve` and have the result be what is passed to `cubeiter`? eg. `(cubeiter (improve ...) x)`

Also you have an error in `abs`. `(-x)` is not the same as `(- x)` which is an abbrevation for `(- 0 x)`. You are calling a procedure called `-x` with no arguments.

The `abs` error makes my think you are perhaps not testing the parts of your code. If you are not you are going to have problems once the code based gets larger. When making `cubeiter` it would be nice to know that the procedures you use in it works and that errors then would most likely be in `cubeiter` and not `improve`, `good-enough`, or `abs`. The whole point of making then individual procedures is to be able to test the parts such that you are sure it works and that you can stop thinking about it's implementation when using it on a higher level of abstraction.